# Disable Safari styles using command line in Macos

Tags: bash, macos, safari, macos-catalina

I want to toggle safari style settings using command line (not apple script) in macos-catalina.
Following are the ways to do it manually:
Launch safari → go to “Develop” menu → Uncheck “Disable styles”

Bash script or bash equivalent command could be helpful to fulfil the need.

Answer (score 0):

### To uncheck disable styles

- /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :WebKitAuthorAndUserStylesEnabledPreferenceKey true"  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
- /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :WebKitPreferences.authorAndUserStylesEnabled true" ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist

### To check disable styles

- /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :WebKitAuthorAndUserStylesEnabledPreferenceKey false"  ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist
- /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :WebKitPreferences.authorAndUserStylesEnabled false" ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Safari/Data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Safari.plist